# Mplayer's synchronization playback not working for more than two videos locally

Tags: video, mplayer

I'm using Mplayer to playback four (security) videos in sync locally.

For the first video, I'm running:

```
mplayer -udp-master -udp-ip 192.168.0.255 1_01_R_072018150000.avi
```

For each of the subsequent videos I'm running:

```
mplayer -udp-slave -udp-ip 192.168.0.255 1_02_R_072018150000.avi
mplayer -udp-slave -udp-ip 192.168.0.255 1_03_R_072018150000.avi
mplayer -udp-slave -udp-ip 192.168.0.255 1_04_R_072018150000.avi
```

All the videos are running in the same machine. I just want to fast forward them in sync.

The thing is: just the first slave plays in sync with the master. The other two start freezed in the first frame and stay that way for 10 or 15 seconds. After that, the playback starts out of sync with the others.

Any help? 
Thanks in advance.

Edit: This is the output from the second slave, for the first 20 seconds or so, while the master and the first of the slaves are running fine and in sync.

```
mplayer -udp-slave -udp-ip 192.168.0.255 1_04_R_072018150000.avi 

MPlayer 1.3.0 (Debian), built with gcc-6.2.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
do_connect: could not connect to socket
connect: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.

Playing 1_04_R_072018150000.avi.
libavformat version 57.56.101 (external)
Mismatching header version 57.56.100
AVI file format detected.
[aviheader] Video stream found, -vid 0
[aviheader] Audio stream found, -aid 1

Badly interleaved AVI file detected - switching to -ni mode...
AVI: No audio stream found -> no sound.
VIDEO:  [H264]  704x576  24bpp  25.000 fps  1214.6 kbps (148.3 kbyte/s)
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
[VO_XV] Could not grab port 110.
[VO_XV] Could not grab port 111.
==========================================================================
Opening video decoder: [ffmpeg] FFmpeg's libavcodec codec family
libavcodec version 57.64.101 (external)
Selected video codec: [ffh264] vfm: ffmpeg (FFmpeg H.264)
==========================================================================
Load subtitles in ./
==========================================================================
Opening audio decoder: [alaw] aLaw/uLaw audio decoder
AUDIO: 8000 Hz, 1 ch, s16le, 64.0 kbit/50.00% (ratio: 8000->16000)
Selected audio codec: [alaw] afm: alaw (aLaw)
==========================================================================
AO: [pulse] 8000Hz 1ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.
VO: [xv] 704x576 => 704x576 Planar YV12 
A:   0.0 V:   0.0 A-V:  0.000 ct:  0.000   1/  1 ??% ??% ??,?% 0 0
```

Comment: I've tried changing the ip address to 127.0.0.1 and even leaving the udp-ip option out, but to no avail.

Comment: The problem might be because your localhost/loopback device does not support broadcast traffic. You may need to run your other slaves on other computers, in VMs or in containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MPlayer documentation](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/HTML/en/MPlayer.html#networksync) says:

> Setting `-udp-ip` to the master's broadcast address allows multiple slaves having the same broadcast address to sync to the master.

I think normally these slaves must run on different machines. Broadcast network stream may get to many machines but in context of every single machine the stream gets bound to a single listening process.

There is a way for multiple processes to receive the same stream (compare [this answer of mine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/445932/108618), `reuseaddr`) but it seems to me that `mplayer` doesn't use it.

I managed to solve the problem on Linux with `socat`, `tee` and `bash`. Since you need to run videos locally, let's stick to `127.0.0.1`; we don't even need broadcasting.

The first command is like the one you used:

```
mplayer -udp-master -udp-ip 127.0.0.1 video0.avi
```

Then run a pipe that will fork the received stream (note: `23867` is the default port used by `mplayer`):

```
socat UDP-LISTEN:23867 - | tee >(socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:127.0.0.1:20001) >(socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:127.0.0.1:20002) >/dev/null
```

This will resend incoming data to ports `20001` and `20002`. You can add `>(socat - UDP-DATAGRAM:127.0.0.1:20003)` and more ports if you want.

With this running, slave `mplayer`-s can bind independently, each one to its own port:

```
mplayer -udp-slave -udp-ip 127.0.0.1 -udp-port 20001 video1.avi
mplayer -udp-slave -udp-ip 127.0.0.1 -udp-port 20002 video2.avi
…
```

Comment: You are awesome,