# How to Play 2 Videos synchronized fullscreen on 2 Monitors?

Tags: video

I want to play 2 Synchronized Videos on 2 Monitors in fullscreen mode.
I know about opening multiple files with vlc, but they are not really synchronized meaning if I stop one the other continues playn etc...

edit:
To be more specific: I want to play 2 different Video files snyced Up

Comment: What OS? Is [`mplayer`](https://superuser.com/q/1340727/432690) an option?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to duplicate your displays.

Most OSes offer a way to configure this in the Display settings, but depending on your setup you could also use a hardware video splitter, which allows multiple physical screens behave as a single logical display, showing exactly the same things.